# jQuery each function $(this) confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

`EXPLANATION`:
I have two  element with as many options inside them.
the first  contains a series of options which have their db-id as their values. these are parents.

the second  element is populated with a list of options which have their parent db-ids as their values and their own db-ids as their html id-attribute. these are children categories.

**PROBLEM:**
I want to have all the children cats to be hidden, and on each select event of any parent category, the relative children to become visible, using their values which is identical to their parent's value.

**MY ATTEMPTS:** 
For this purpose, I have written the following script which does not work. It attaches a click event to each parent category, and this event triggers a function which is responsible to turn the visibility of any child cat on, if their values matches the values of the clicked element.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<select multiple  name="branch" >
<option selected="" value="false">Please Select a Branch</option>
<option class="branch-item" value="0">Computer</option>
<option class="branch-item" value="1">Automobile</option>
<option class="branch-item" value="4">Technical</option>
</select>   

<select multiple class="form-option" name="subbranch" >
<option class="subbranch-item" style="display: none;" value="1">Software</option>
<option class="subbranch-item" style="display: none;" value="1">Hardware</option>
<option class="subbranch-item" style="display: none;" value="7">Mechanics</option>
<option class="subbranch-item" style="display: none;" value="7">Welding</option>   
</select>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $(".branche-item").click(function(){
            var values = $(this).val();
            $('.subbranch-item').parent().each(function(element, value) {
                if(value == values)
                {
                    element.show(); 
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

I appreciate any help on the debugging of the jquery code, thanks

Comment: I hope the spelling 'branche-item' is not throwing this off.

Comment: You have two select objects.  When a `branch-item` is selected in one of them, what exactly do you want to have happen with the other select item?  Do you just want to select any items with matching value?

Comment: yes i want to show all options within the second select element that have a value identical to the selected option of first select element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $sub = $('select[name="subbranch"]');
var sub = $.trim($sub.html());

$('select[name="branch"]').change(function () {
    var filter = $(this).children('option:selected').map(function () {
        return '[value="' + this.value + '"]'
    }).get().join();

    $sub.empty().append($(sub).filter(filter))
}).change()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F9777/)

Comment: thanks. But this has an issue. There is a mismatch in selection. the mechanism of hide/show works perfect, but selecting parent X, it shown children parent Y

Comment: @MostafaTalebi can you give an example

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select[name="branch"]').change(function () {
    var $branch = $(this).children(':selected'),
        $subbranch = $('[name="subbranch"]').children('option');

    $subbranch.hide()

    $branch.each(function () {
        var branch = $(this).val();
        $subbranch.each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == branch) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
}).change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F9777/3/